# How can I stop accidentally removing basic authentication?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, version-control

I have a site with a "production" version that should not require basic authentication, and several "development" versions which should.  I implement this by including an "AuthType Basic" directive in the top-level .htaccess for the development site only.  The top-level .htaccess is not empty on the production site- it is needed for the site to function- it just must have this extra directive added for the development site.

The production and development sites each run off their own branches in git.  The problem is: I keep accidentally replacing the top-level .htaccess file in one or more development versions with the production one, thus undoing the password protection.  I understand that I can avoid this through discipline in merging practices.  However, I only work on this project once a month or so and it is very easy to forget about this and accidentally undo the .htaccess customizations.

Is there a way I can have an identical .htaccess on my production and development sites, yet still arrange for the development site but not the production site to require basic authentication?

Here are some ideas, I don't know which can be done via .htaccess -

- conditional logic based on server name
- include another (non-versioned) .htaccess file
- test value of an environment variable

I can only modify .htaccess; not the server-wide apache configuration.

Comment: do you have access to the apache server/vhost config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to server/vhost config, then you can indeed use conditional logic by checking the hostname. You can do this with a combination of `SetEnvIfNoCase` to check the hostname, and `Satisfy Any` to allow bypassing the `Require` directive. It'll look something like:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host production.example.com norequire_auth=yes

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

Of course, your auth stuff will look like whatever you need, but if the requested host is "production.example.com" then the "norequire_auth" environment variable gets set and the line:

```
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

bypasses the authentication.